# Django: django-registration reverse lookup fails

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration and in my settings.py I have set the login and logout urls as

```
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/users/logout/'
```

and in the urls.py I have set

```
url(r'^users/', include('registration.backends.default.urls', namespace='users')),
```

Everything works fine except when I try to got to localhost:8000/users/passwords/reset there is an error

```
NoReverseMatch at /users/password/reset/
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

However, when I add this line to the urls.py file everything works correctly

```
(r'^users/', include('registration.auth_urls')),
```

This solution is confusing me because registration.backends.default.urls includes the line

```
(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
```

which should be doing the same thing as the line added to my project's urls.py file. Why does adding the line to the project's urls.py file fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying a `namespace` parameter with your include. This results in, among other things, you having to supply the namespace also when using the `reverse()` function or `{% url %}` in templates.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces for further information.

Comment: doesn't the included registration.auth_urls in registration.backends.default.urls also provide a namespace as well?

Comment: So is there no way to include the auth urls from a namespaced app?

Answer (score 0):

Because the first one includes `users/` in the url regex, which is what you're trying to reach.

Comment: yes but doesn't registration.backends.default.urls already include registration.auth_urls at the users/ url?